# C++ Custom Assert

Tags: c++, c++11, expression, assert

I am trying to write my own custom assert for my own project. This project will be written with c++11.

The assert must have the following qualities:

It must be kept as an expression and is assignable.
E.g. I should be able to write code like this `int x = custom_assert(1/y);`

It must be overloaded to accept an assert with a message and without one.
E.g `int x = custom_assert(1/y, "Error divide by zero");` This code and the above are both compilable and acceptable.

It must have no side-effects in release mode
E.g. `int x = custom_assert(1/y);` will become `int x = 1/y;` in release mode.

And most importantly, it must break at the specific point where the assert was made. Which will make use of `__debugbreak()` as part of its evaluating expression.

The following is my attempt:

```
#include <string>

bool DoLog(std::string msg, std::string file, int line); //Prints to std::cerr and returns HALT macro


#if defined(_DEBUG) || defined(DEBUG)
#define HALT true
#define NT_ASSERT_BASE(x, msg) (!(x) && DoLog((msg), __FILE__, __LINE__) && (__debugbreak(),1))
#else
#define HALT false
#define NT_ASSERT_BASE(x,msg) (x)
#endif//debug/release defines

//--- Can't implement these until I can return the expression ---
//#define GET_MACRO(_1,_2,_3,NAME,...) NAME
//#define FOO(...) GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, FOO3, FOO2)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define NT_ASSERT(expression, msg) NT_ASSERT_BASE(expression,msg)
```

As you can see my custom assert fails on 2 fronts, namely being kept as expression and assignable, and on overloading (Which I cannot implement until I figure out how to keep it as an expression.

All in all, I may be chasing stars and this macro may in fact be impossible to make. (Which I hope isn't the case)

Many thanks.

Comment: Are restricted from using c++11/14?

Comment: C++11 is allowed for the project

Comment: By the way, assert-like expressions that are *preserved* in release mode (minus the actual assert) are, I believe, called ["verify" expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85bwt63a.aspx), though this may be a Microsoft-ism. In general, I believe it's considered surprising when `assert` code is preserved in a release build.

Comment: This needs some clarification.  Given `x = custom_assert(1/y);`, what is the condition that trips the "assertion"?  You example suggests that it's divide-by-zero, but your attempt suggests that it's simply the expression evaluating to 0.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, this **can't be done in standard C++**.

There is no way to get the `__debugbreak()` into the expanded code and at the same time pass the result of the expression unmodified, because you need the result twice: once for testing it, which will implicitly cast it to `bool`, and once to return it at the end.

There are two options:

- Use gcc's and clang's [`({})`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) construct with `auto` variable to hold the result. That will exclude MSC++, but I suppose you want that, because `__debugbreak()` is a MSC++ misfeature.
- Give up on requiring the `__debugbreak()` on the call site, accept having to go one level up when it stops and make the thing as a template function.

  - A lambda expression will fit slightly better than a template function. It will make the break appear at the macro site, but it will still appear as a separate stack frame in the call stack. It also requires C++11 support (it was published over 5 years ago, but some platforms may not have it).

Comment: Can't a lambda do that? `[](bool b, const char* msg){ /* code */ }(param1, param2)`

Comment: We use the second suggestion at my work and it works OK; having the debugger break inside the templated function that checks the expression is not that bad; Another trick is to lazily evaluate the message when you have it, which can be achieved by stuffing it into a lambda - I've seen places where the assert never hits but printing the message is quite hot in a profiler.

Comment: @StoryTeller, true, I forgot about that (we are still stuck with MSC++ 15.0, so I can't use them at work). A lambda should still show up as frame in the call stack (at least in Debug build), but it will be the right place in the code listing.

Comment: @ChristopherLeong, since you have C++11, you can also try the lambda, but it will still show up as an extra stack frame.

Comment: Why do you say `__debugbreak()` is a misfeature?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should be mixing the validation with the assignment.  From your example, it looks like you want to assign to an integer but an assertion, by nature, is a boolean expression.  Further, your example is asserting on the wrong expression.  It looks like you want to assert that y is not equal to zero (preventing division by zero), but you are asserting against something that will also be one or false or undefined.

If you are willing to be a bit flexible with your assignment requirements, then we can work around the problem of maintaining the expression and other useful info with some macro magic.  Further, we can execute the __debugbreak() at the call site.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<class Fun>
inline bool DoLog(Fun f, std::string message, const char *expression, const char *filename, int line) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<bool, decltype(f())>::value, "Predicate must return a bool.");
    if (!(f())) {
        std::cerr << filename << '@' << line << ": '" << expression << "' is false.";
        if (!message.empty()) {
            std::cerr << ' ' << message;
        }
        std::cerr << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

#if defined(_DEBUG) || defined(DEBUG)
#define HALT true

#define WITH_MESSAGE_(expr, x) [&](){return (expr);}, x, #expr
#define WITHOUT_MESSAGE_(expr) [&](){return (expr);}, std::string{}, #expr
#define PICK_ASSERTION_ARGS_(_1, _2, WHICH_, ...) WHICH_
#define CREATE_ASSERTION_ARGS_(...) PICK_ASSERTION_ARGS_(__VA_ARGS__, WITH_MESSAGE_, WITHOUT_MESSAGE_)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NT_ASSERT(...) if (!DoLog(CREATE_ASSERTION_ARGS_(__VA_ARGS__), __FILE__, __LINE__)) __debugbreak()
#else
#define HALT false
#define NT_ASSERT(...)
#endif

int main() {
    NT_ASSERT(true);
    NT_ASSERT(false);
    NT_ASSERT(1 == 1, "1 is 1");
    NT_ASSERT(1 == 0, "1 is not 0");
    return 0;
}
```

*NOTE: The above snippet works on GCC using -std=c++11 (with a placeholder for the __debugbreak() statement).  I'm making an assumption that VC++ would work also when it fully supports C++11.*

Comment: Why shouldn't I mix validations with assignments? I would assume that a validation is to prove that the code is handled properly and the testing environment can be easily removed without changing much code.

My biggest concern is the iterative usage of having multi-liners which only accommodate the validation macro .e.g.:



`bool isOpened = SomeSerializer->OpenFile("somefile.txt");
assert(isOpened);
if(isOpened) {//code using the file}`



This seems more elegant in comparison:
`if ( assert(SomeSerializer->Open("somefile.txt")) )
{//code using the file}`

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do then.  From the original problem, you used the example of int x = NT_ASSERT(1/y)  In this case, what are you trying to actually assert?  To me, the logical thing to assert is that y is not 0.  Am I misunderstanding the requirement?  If not, then NT_ASSERT(1/y) is not enough.  You would need something like int x = NT_ASSERT(1/y, y!=0, "y can't be zero")  In other words, the original requirements seem to be missing the predicate upon which to assert.  It simply has the expression you wish to evaluate.